# return a 2d array without brackets

Tags: python, function, numpy, multidimensional-array, discord.py

I'm trying to create a function that returns a 2d array without the brackets on the sides of the array, And I can't use `print` since I'm using this function for a discord bot and want to `return` the array instead of printing it.

Here's some of my code:

```
import numpy as np

example_array = np.array([["⚪", "⚪", "⚪"], ["⚪", "⚪", "⚪"], ["⚪", "⚪", "⚪"]])

def get_array():
    for row in example_array:
        return "".join(map(str,row))

X = print_array()
```

Here's the output if I print/send `X`:

⚪⚪⚪

How can I use a function to return the full array?

Comment: Your function returns on the *first iteration always*. It isn't clear what exactly want as an output, but you have to build it up with the loop *and then return* after the loop

Comment: As an aside, why are you using `numpy` here???

Comment: Note, it seems like you want your function to *create a string* not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is something like this

```
"".join(["".join(i) for i in example_array])
```

would give us

'⚪⚪⚪⚪⚪⚪⚪⚪⚪'

Comment: Wasn't what I was looking for but works with adding a "\n" at the beginning, like:
"\n".join(["".join(i) for i in example_array])
Thanks!